# DayPilot Month and Navigator

Tags: c#, asp.net, daypilot

I'm currently using DayPilot Month as an event calendar. I use DayPilot Navigator to change the weeks.

But I have problems binding the Navigator to the Month.

[image]

When i try to debug it, it shows this.

[image]

I'm using Visual studios 2013, webform asp.net, c#. Can someone help me please!!

Edit:

I got it to work, but whenever I click on a different week, all my data are gone. So there is no events in my calendar at all. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your code and error message as a text, not as an image. And error message isn't clear?

Comment: I had trouble putting it in blockquote so i used an image as its easier. What do you mean it's not clear?